# Resize the canvas around a bitmap?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

**Take the below image I will use for the following examples:**

The dimensions unchaged are currently `96 x 71`

[image]

Lets say I wanted to resize the canvas to `115 x 80` - the resulting image should then be:

[image]

Finally if I resized it to a smaller size than the original canvas was, eg `45 x 45` the output would appear like so:

[image]

**This is what I have tried so far:**

```
procedure ResizeBitmapCanvas(Bitmap: TBitmap; H, W: Integer);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Source, Dest: TRect;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Source := Rect(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
    Dest := Source;
    Dest.Offset(Bitmap.Width div 2, Bitmap.Height div 2);
    Bitmap.SetSize(W, H);
    Bmp.Assign(Bitmap);
    Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Source);
    Bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(Dest, Bitmap.Canvas, Source);
    Bitmap.Assign(Bmp);
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ResizeBitmapCanvas(Image1.Picture.Bitmap, 110, 110);
end;
```

If you try the above on a bitmap loaded into a TImage the actual bitmap does not center, the canvas does change size however.

The properties I have set for the Image are:

```
Image1.AutoSize := True;
Image1.Center   := True;
Image1.Stretch  := False;
```

I think it could be the line `Dest.Offset(Bitmap.Width div 2, Bitmap.Height div 2);` which needs looking at, to calculate the correct center position?

The code has been adapted/modified slightly from a recent question David Heffernan answered.

**How do I resize the canvas that surrounds a bitmap, but without stretching the bitmap?**

Comment: No problem, I've asked for them because I think they are important here since you are changing the `TImage.Picture.Bitmap` size.

Comment: Yes you are right, I completely overlooked it :)

Comment: So, isn't that what causes the behavior, The `AutoSize` ? Try with the plain image with a picture inside, set only the `Center` to True and resize the `TImage` in a form designer. You will see the *surrounding canvas*; isn't that what you are asking for ?

Comment: no because I think AutoSize only works based on the size of the canvas - not the actual bitmap, which is been manipulated inside the ResizeBitmapCanvas procedure. As for the center the image I guess that is the same, but I needed it for bitmaps not TImage.

Comment: If you keep the `AutoSize = True` and change the `TImage.Picture.Bitmap` size (what you are actually doing) it will resize the `TImage` component, not it's canvas, the canvas size equals to the graphics content inside, that's what I was thinking about, but never mind, you've got the answer and that's the point ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
procedure ResizeBitmapCanvas(Bitmap: TBitmap; H, W: Integer; BackColor: TColor);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Source, Dest: TRect;
  Xshift, Yshift: Integer;
begin
  Xshift := (Bitmap.Width-W) div 2;
  Yshift := (Bitmap.Height-H) div 2;

  Source.Left := Max(0, Xshift);
  Source.Top := Max(0, Yshift);
  Source.Width := Min(W, Bitmap.Width);
  Source.Height := Min(H, Bitmap.Height);

  Dest.Left := Max(0, -Xshift);
  Dest.Top := Max(0, -Yshift);
  Dest.Width := Source.Width;
  Dest.Height := Source.Height;

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.SetSize(W, H);
    Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackColor;
    Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, W, H));
    Bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(Dest, Bitmap.Canvas, Source);
    Bitmap.Assign(Bmp);
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I can't remember if XE supports setting `Width` and `Height` for a `TRect`. If not then change the code to

```
Source.Right := Source.Left + Min(W, Bitmap.Width);
```

and so on.

Comment: if the bits around the edge you mean the canvas outside the bitmap then that would be to fill it with a color like before. I have been playing around with your earlier code, hence the one I posted in the question is adapted. I thought I could tweak it for this purpose but have been unable to.

Comment: That is precisely right thanks David. On the line `Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, W, H));` where did you come up with 0, 0 in the parameters? Is this just telling it to fill the rect from the top left most pixel?

Comment: Yes, that fills the entire output bitmap with your chosen background colour